# How to run single UI test in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

When I run tests in XCode's Test Navigator, it always runs test cases from the first one. When I choose second, third, etc. it will always execute every previous tests.

It seems that this issue could be in project settings in Xcode, because in another project it works properly and it is possible to run only single test case, no matter of order.

Is there any option in settings to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean? just hit the run button in front of any specific test you want.

Comment: It's not working for me. It will start all tests as I have already mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

Run specific test by either from left side of the testing code:

[image]

or from the test navigation pan:

[image]

**Note that** in this image:

- First one (with the white lego icon) is "Test module", it will run all test of the module.
- second one (with the capital `T` icon) is the test class, it will run all test functions within.
- Third and forth items (with the lowercase `t` icon) are the test case, each one will run **just the specific test**

Comment: As I wrote above, when I run test from Test Navigator as you explained (e. g. the forth item from your screenshot), it will execute the first one and then second one. It's not working for me.

Comment: It would be nice if you upload your sample project with the test. So I can investigate on the issue.